# How can I make a binary tree?

Tags: binary-tree, mips

I am doing a homework on MIPS and the assignment is to create a binary tree in MIPS that would accept double precision floating point numbers and allocate space dynamically. Does anyone have any examples of binary trees in MIPS that I can use?

Comment: MIPS as in... the assembly language?

Comment: yes, like this http://vhouten.home.xs4all.nl/mipsel/r3000-isa.html

Comment: Assuming that you are not expected to write you own dynamic allocator, you have not fully specified your working environment.

Comment: @dmckee sorry I didn't understand what you mean. When we were doing linked lists, we done the allocation with                            li $v0,9 syscall

Answer (score 3):

If you know how to create arrays in MIPS, you can just project a binary tree onto an array. It will more or less be a huge waste of space, but it will work semi-simply.

First determine how you are going to organize a node in memory on the stack. I would organize it:

```
[data to store] #presumably floating point numbers
[address of left node]
[address of right node]
```

designate a null value for the node, probably 0x7ff...f

designate a null address, probably 0

create an array of size :  (2^n  -  1)  *   NodeSize
where n = the depth of the deepest branch of the tree counting from 1, not 0. NodeSize is the number of words needed to describe a node.

The index of the array will correspond the the pattern described below.

```
     0
   /   \
  1     2
 / \   / \
3   4 5   6
```

It will be somewhat difficult to work with, but it should work. I suppose technically you either don't need the array to index null values if you manage the tree well, or if you keep it in the format I described, you don't really need to save the addresses of the other nodes because they are implied by their indexes. So really you only need one or the other. You should really choose which one would be easier by figuring out how much you want to work with addresses and how full your tree is going to be. If your tree is full, the implied edges are helpful by saving space.

tl;dr This will waste space by describing a tree in two ways. Remove the array idea or the addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar project.

My solution was as follows:

```
##################################################
#
#   Binary Search Tree - Project 1
#
#   First Assembly Program :)
#
##################################################
.data
nl: .asciiz "\n"
prompt1: "\nPlease select an option from the list below:\n"
prompt2: "[A] - Add a record to the tree\n"
prompt3: "[F] - Find a record in the tree\n"
prompt4: "[P] - Perform a preorder traversal\n"
prompt5: "[I] - Perform an inorder traversal\n"
prompt6: "[Q] - Quit the program\n"
prompt7: "\nChoose a character: "
empty: "\nThe Tree is Empty."
youentered: "\nYou Entered: "
recordfound: "\nRecord Found: "
recordnotfound: "\nRecord Not Found! "
goodbye: "\nGoodbye!"
addid: "\nEnter the ID to add: "
addyear: "Enter the year: "
addtitle: "Enter the title: "
adddescription: "Enter the description: "
id: "\nID: "
year: "\nYear: "
title: "\nTitle: "
description: "Description: "
#idsize: .word 0
#optiona: 97    addrecord   a
#optionf: 102   findrecord  f
#optionp: 112   preorder    p
#optioni: 105   inorder     i
#optionq: 113   quit        q
###################################################################
#
#   Note: I reuse a lot of print statements
#   This code is far from what I would call optimized
#   
#   This is my first assembly program and I'm really just
#   Happy to see it all working :)
#
#   I spent about 18 hours writing this so lol :)
#
#   The only thing that I've gotten to crash it so far is
#   Entering characters when it's waiting for an int :)
#
######################################################
#
#   Here is my memory setup:
#
#   $s5 - Stores Root Node
#   $s7 - Stores Size of Tree (Not Really Necessary)
#
#   Each New Item Contains a chunk of 344 bytes
#   The bytes are setup as such:
#
#   8 Bytes - [ID]
#   8 Bytes - [Year]
#   64 Bytes - [Title]
#   256 Bytes - [Description]
#   8 Bytes - [LeftNodeAddress]
#   8 Bytes - [RightNodeAddress]
#
#
#   Example Tree:
#
#                        10        -Root
#                      /    \
#                     7     15     -Branch
#                    / \   /  \
#                   6  9  12   17  -Leaf
#
#   In Memory:
#
#       [Offset: 328] - [ID] - [Offset: 336]
#             |                       |
# [Off: 328][ID][Off:336] [Off: 328][ID][Off: 336] . . . 
#
#
########################################################
.text 
###################
##Prompt Function##
###################
prompt:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt1         #Please select an option from the list below:
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt2         #[A] - Add a record to the tree
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt3         #[F] - Find a record in the tree
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt4         #[P] - Preorder traversal
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt5         #[I] - Inorder traversal
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt6         #[Q] - Quit the program
syscall
###################
##Get User Input ##
################### 
getinput:   
li $v0, 4           #Choose a character:
la $a0, prompt7
syscall

li $v0, 12          #Read a single character from console
syscall

move $s0, $v0

beq $s0, 97, addrecord      #If you press 'a', addrecord
beq $s0, 102, findrecord    #If you press 'f', findrecord
beq $s0, 112, preorder      #If you press 'p', preorder
beq $s0, 105, inorder       #If you press 'i', inorder
beq $s0, 113, exit      #If you press 'q', exit

li $v0, 4           #If you press something random
la $a0, nl          #Display new line
syscall

j getinput          #And ask for a new character
###################
## Add A Record  ##
###################
addrecord:
li $v0, 9           #allocate memory for new record
li $a0, 344         #enough memory for 2 addresses and all the data
syscall


move $s0, $v0           #hang onto the initial address of all our info

li $v0, 4           #prompt for ID
la $a0, addid
syscall

li $v0, 5           #enter integer
syscall

sw $v0, 0($s0)          #store our ID into memory   Offset: 0

li $v0, 4           #prompt for add year
la $a0, addyear
syscall

li $v0, 5           #enter integer
syscall

sw $v0, 4($s0)          #store year into our memory Offset: 4

li $v0, 4           #prompt for add title
la $a0, addtitle
syscall

li $v0, 8           #read our title into the allocated space
la $a0, 8($s0)          #Offset: 8
li $a1, 64
syscall

li $v0, 4           #prompt for add description
la $a0, adddescription
syscall

li $v0, 8           #read our description into the allocated space
la $a0, 72($s0)         #Offset: 72
li $a1, 256
syscall 

bne $s7, 0, setlocations    #if this isn't root node let's set the locations

add $s7, $s7, 1         #add 1 to the size of the records

move $s5, $s0           #store this address as root node for now

j prompt
########################
##Set Memory Locations##
########################
setlocations:
move $s6, $s5           #Keep $s5 as  our root and use $s6 as temporary storage
move $s4, $s6           #Use $s4 to find the null node slot
storelocations:
beqz $s4, store         #If we've reached a leaf, store
lw $t2, 0($s4)          #get ID from current node
lw $t1, 0($s0)          #get Current ID from new node node we're adding
ble $t1,$t2,goleft      #get left location if new node <= current node
move $s6, $s4
lw $s4, 336($s4)        #get node to the right if new node > current node
li $t3, 336         #be ready to store to the right slot
j storelocations
goleft:
move $s6, $s4
lw $s4, 328($s4)        #load the node to the left
li $t3, 328         #be ready to store to the left slot
j storelocations
store:
beq $t3, 336, storeright    #if $t3 was set to storeRight, then store to the right
sw $s0, 328($s6)        #else store the new node's location into our node's left slot
add $s7, $s7, 1         #remind our size register that it's growing
j prompt            #back to the prompt
storeright:
sw $s0, 336($s6)        #store new node to the right slot
j prompt            #back to the prompt
########################
## Find Record by ID  ##
########################
findrecord:
move $s6, $s5
bne $s7, 0, search
li $v0, 4           #if tree is empty
la $a0, empty           #display message Tree is empty
syscall
j prompt            #and go wait for input
search:
move $s6, $s5
li $v0, 4           #print ID:
la $a0, id
syscall

li $v0, 5           #let user enter ID
syscall

move $t1, $v0           #store the id we're looking for in $t1
checkagain: 
lw $t2, ($s6)           #store the id we're currently looking at
bne $t1, $t2, checkempty    #if this isn't the right ID, is it the last one?
###########################
##If we find the record:
###########################
li $v0, 4
la $a0, recordfound     #Record Found: 
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print ID:
la $a0, id
syscall

li $v0, 1           #Print the ID stored at $s6     [Offset: 0]
lw $a0, 0($s6)
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print Year:
la $a0, year
syscall

li $v0, 1           #Print the Year stored at $s6   [Offset: 4]
lw $a0, 4($s6)
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print Title:
la $a0, title
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print the Title stored at $s6  [Offset: 8]
la $a0, 8($s6)
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print Description:
la $a0, description
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print descript stored at $s6   [Offset: 72]
la $a0, 72($s6)
syscall

j getinput

checkempty:
ble $t1, $t2, checkleft     #If $t1 <= $t2 check the left node
lw $s6, 336($s6)        #Otherwise check the right node
bne $s6, 0, checkagain      #If this record isn't empty, check again
li $v0, 4           #Otherwise
la $a0, recordnotfound      #Record not found
syscall
j getinput
checkleft:
lw $s6, 328($s6)        #Check the left node
bne $s6, 0, checkagain      #If the record isn't empty, check again
li $v0, 4           #Otherwise
la $a0, recordnotfound      #Record not found
syscall
j getinput
treeempty:
li $v0, 4           #if tree is empty
la $a0, empty           #display message Tree is empty
syscall
j prompt
#####################################
#
#   The Inorder Function
#
#####################################
inorder:
beq $s7, 0, treeempty       #If the tree is empty display empty message
move $s6, $s5           #$s6 is the record we're currently at
move $t0, $s6           #t0 will iterate $s6 is our starting node
move $t1, $t0           #t1 will be thrown on the stack to keep track of everything
jal printinorder
j prompt
printinorder:
addi $sp, $sp, -12      #allocate 8 bytes for the stack
sw $ra, 0($sp)          #4 for the $ra variable
sw $t1, 4($sp)          #4 for $t1

bne $t0, 0, dontreturn      #if $t0 isn't null don't return
lw $ra, 0($sp)          #otherwise:
lw $t1, 4($sp)          #pop stack
addi $sp, $sp, 12       #and prepare
jr $ra              #to return
dontreturn:
move $t1, $t0           #put $t0 in $t1
lw $t0, 328($t0)        #load the next pointer to the left
jal printinorder        #and recurse back to printorder
move $s6, $t1           #if we're back here, it's time to print
j goprint           #so go print
afterprint:
move $t0, $t1           #after we print, move $t1 back to $t0
lw $t0, 336($t0)        #get the next pointer to the right
jal printinorder        #recurse to see if it's the last one
move $s6, $t1           #if we made it here, it is, let's print
beq $s6, $t1, done      #if we already printed this one, we're done (Root Node)
j goprint           #Go print the node to the right
done:
lw $ra, 0($sp)          #if we're done, pop our stack
lw $t1, 4($sp)          #clean it up
addi $sp, $sp, 12       #8 bytes worth
jr $ra              #and return
goprint:
li $v0, 4           #Print ID:
la $a0, id
syscall

li $v0, 1           #Print the ID stored at $s6     [Offset: 0]
lw $a0, 0($s6)
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print Year:
la $a0, year
syscall

li $v0, 1           #Print the Year stored at $s6   [Offset: 4]
lw $a0, 4($s6)
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print Title:
la $a0, title
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print the Title stored at $s6  [Offset: 8]
la $a0, 8($s6)
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print Description:
la $a0, description
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print descript stored at $s6   [Offset: 72]
la $a0, 72($s6)
syscall

j afterprint

#####################################
#
#   The Preorder Function
#
#####################################
preorder:
beq $s7, 0, treeempty       #If the tree is empty display empty message
move $s6, $s5           #$s6 is the record we're currently at
move $t0, $s6           #t0 will iterate $s6 is our starting node
move $t1, $t0           #t1 will be thrown on the stack to keep track of everything
jal printpreorder
j prompt
printpreorder:
addi $sp, $sp, -12      #allocate 8 bytes for the stack
sw $ra, 0($sp)          #4 for the $ra variable
sw $t1, 4($sp)          #4 for $t1
bne $t0, 0, dontreturnpo    #if $t0 isn't null don't return
lw $ra, 0($sp)          #otherwise:
lw $t1, 4($sp)          #pop stack
addi $sp, $sp, 12       #and prepare
jr $ra              #to return
dontreturnpo:
move $s6, $t0           #if we made it here, it is, let's print
j goprintpo         #so go print
afterprintpo:
move $t1, $t0           #put $t0 in $t1
lw $t0, 328($t0)        #load the next pointer to the left
jal printpreorder       #and recurse back to printorder
move $t0, $t1           #after we print, move $t1 back to $t0
lw $t0, 336($t0)        #get the next pointer to the right
jal printpreorder       #recurse to see if it's the last one
donepo:
lw $ra, 0($sp)          #if we're done, pop our stack
lw $t1, 4($sp)          #clean it up
addi $sp, $sp, 12       #8 bytes worth
jr $ra              #and return
goprintpo:
li $v0, 4           #Print ID:
la $a0, id
syscall

li $v0, 1           #Print the ID stored at $s6     [Offset: 0]
lw $a0, 0($s6)
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print Year:
la $a0, year
syscall

li $v0, 1           #Print the Year stored at $s6   [Offset: 4]
lw $a0, 4($s6)
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print Title:
la $a0, title
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print the Title stored at $s6  [Offset: 8]
la $a0, 8($s6)
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print Description:
la $a0, description
syscall

li $v0, 4           #Print descript stored at $s6   [Offset: 72]
la $a0, 72($s6)
syscall

j afterprintpo

exit:
li $v0, 4           #Say
la $a0, goodbye         #Goodbye!
syscall

li $v0, 10          #Terminate Program
syscall
```